# backref in mcite not displaying parethesis

Tags: biblatex, mcite, backref

I just migrated to `biblatex` from BibTeX. I am using the `mcite` option to combine some references. I am also using `backref` option for reverse page lookup.
I get the correct display of "(cit on p #)" on the regular references.

However, the `mcite` references do not have the parenthesis, just "cit on pp #1, #2".

How can I get the parenthesis to show in both cases?

[image]

Here are my remaining packages:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=phys,articletitle=true,
biblabel=brackets,
pageranges=false,
autocite = superscript,
mcite = true,
natbib = true,
subentry = true,
hyperref=auto,
backref=true,
sortsets=true,
% doi=true
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: While it was fairly easy to understand and reproduce your issue here, it would still greatly help if you could include an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) in your future questions. An MWE is a nice way to say that you care about the people trying to help you. It helps us to get started more quickly and focus on the issue at hand and it makes sure we all talk about the same thing.

Comment: I apologize. I'd keep it in mind. Tired brain last night. 
And thanks, your solution below worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This apparent inconsistency between the backrefs for `@set` and other entries has been present since at least version 1.7 of `biblatex` and is not confined to `biblatex-phys`. All standard styles and I assume many custom styles behave similarly.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=phys,
  subentry = true,
  backref=true,
  sortsets=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
% change punctuation before the backref part
% from phys.bbx
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{set}{%
  \entryset
    {%
      \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
        {\printfield[bibentrysetcount]{entrysetcount}%
         \setunit*{\addnbspace}}
        {}%
     }
    {%
      \ifdef{\bbx@set@journal}
        {}
        {\savefield{journaltitle}{\bbx@set@journal}}%
      \ifdef{\bbx@set@namehash}
        {}
        {\savefield{namehash}{\bbx@set@namehash}}%
    }%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{setpageref}%
  \finentry
  \global\undef\bbx@set@namehash
  \global\undef\bbx@set@journal
}
\makeatother

% we just added the "[parens]" in line 4, the rest is verbatim from biblatex.def
\renewbibmacro*{setpageref}{%
  \iflistundef{pageref}
    {}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,stdmodel}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there supposed to be a perion before the (cit. on p. 1)? With you fix, how can I add a period? I am not sure if it's proper grammar or just aesthetics.

Comment: @Godey A period before parentheses looks a bit weird to my eyes in most situations. But it should be as easy as `\renewcommand*{\bibpagerefpunct}{\addperiod\space}`.

Comment: You are awesome!